# Drupal 7 - rollback current transaction

Tags: drupal, transactions, drupal-7

I am writing a module in Drupal 7 which uses the `hook_node_insert`. If something goes wrong, I want to get the current transaction and roll it back. For example:

```
try{
    ...
}catch(Exception $e){
    transaction->rollback();
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get the `transaction` object as the actual transaction is created in the function calling my hook function.

Perhaps I can cause somehow Drupal to rollback the `transaction`. Is there perhaps a flag in the [$form_state](https://drupal.org/node/1850410) I can use?

Is this feasible in drupal? I suppose it is but I cannot find how to do it...

Comment: If something goes wrong the transaction will be rolled back anyway...what are you trying to achieve that isn't already there?

Comment: @Clive I am trying to define "wrong". The transaction will be rollbacked if someone throws an unhandled exception, or if an error occurs. Since my "save" action involves a file upload I want to have full control in order to delete the file too...